# Windows 10: Sending multicast UDP messages from ethernet interface to WSL2 fails

Tags: windows-10, udp, multicast, wsl-2

I have the following **setup**:

- external device that sends multicast UDP messages through ethernet towards a windows 10 PC
- The PC has WSL2 running and within an application that is trying to listen to these multicast messages.
- The multicast channel is fixed and the IP address of the device is Automatic Private IP address (169.254.x.x range), there is no DHCP
- The multicast setup in the above paragraph has to be assumed as immutable, which means I cannot change the code, that does the multicasting and the listening
- This setup works, as intended when the listener application is on windows and is in the same Automatic Private IP range as the remote device
- The IP of the external device can be pinged from within WSL2

**Issue:**

At the moment, the listener application cannot receive any multicast messages in WSL2, so it cannot recognize the external device.

**Question:**

How can I route the UDP messages to the WSL2 interface? - I assume the root cause is, that the multicast happens in a different subnet (169.254.x.x), than what WSL2 uses (172.24.x.x gateway).

If the above assumption is wrong, the question is what could be the issue?